# >> operator - poor man's loop in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, monads

I don't know Haskell, I just wanted to play around with it in order to learn it.  I was trying to understand io, monads, etc. and wrote this in the interpreter (GHCi, version 7.10.2, WinGHCI):

```
Prelude> [1,1] >> "ok"
"okok"
Prelude> [1,1,1] >> "ok"
"okokok"
Prelude> [1..10] >> "ok"
"okokokokokokokokokok"
Prelude> [1] >> "ok" >> [1] >> "ok"
"okok"
Prelude> [1,2] >> "ok" >> [1,2] >> "ok"
"okokokokokokokok"
Prelude> [1..10] >> [1..10]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Care to explain?  Why does the number of elements in the list affect how many times "ok" is written (or in the last case, the number of times an array is written)?  The >> operator isn't supposed to do this, is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First note that this has nothing whatsoever to do with `IO`. It has to do with monads, but with a very specific one: the list monad.

```
instance Monad [] where
  return x = [x]
  f >>= xs = concat $ map f xs   -- aka `(>>=) = concatMap`.
```

It is best know for *list comprehensions*, which are basically syntactic sugar<sup>†</sup>:

```
[ result x y z | x <- bla, y <- foo x, z <- bar ]
```

translates to

```
bla >>=
   \x -> foo x >>=
            \y -> bar >>=
                     \z -> return (result x y z)
```

Now, `a>>b` is only a short-cut to `a >>= \_ -> b`, i.e. it ignores the values contained in the LHS monadic action, but “pretends” to use them in the RHS nonetheless. So, `[1,1,1] >> "ok"` is the same as

```
[ "ok" | _ <- [1,1,1] ]
```

at least almost...actually that's the same as `[1,1,1] >> return "ok"`, i.e. `>> ["ok"]`, which will give

```
["ok", "ok", "ok"]
```

If you omit the singleton `return`, each `"ok"` will not be wrapped in a list and those concatenated, rather the strings themselves are all concatenated by the monadic bind. And that's how you get `"okokok"`.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>The equivalent default implementation is actually a bit different, but with the `-XMonadComprehensions` extension, list comprehensions really work this way.</sub>

Comment: So I am inadvertently using the list monad, not a list?  I guess a true list wouldn't even be accepted by the interpreter in that line of code?

Comment: @user3355020: sure it's a list, as true as any. Talking of the _list monad_ just means we're focusing on one particular feature/property of lists.